# How type coercion happens when [] == false?

Tags: javascript

ECMA script [documentation](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_11.9.3) says in ***abstract equality comparison alogorithm*** that,

> If Type(y) is Boolean, return the result of the comparison x ==
>   ToNumber(y).

So for instance, `[] == false` will be coerced like,

```
1.   [] == Number(false)
2.   [] == 0 //comparison happens here.
```

My question is, the coercion will be happened recursively until the two operands becomes primitive or not? How exactly the coercion happens here?

I presume the coercion will be repeated until the conversion of two operands to primitive, like below

```
1.   [] == Number(false)
2.   [] == 0
3.   ToPrimitive([]) == 0
4.   0 == 0 
5.   true
```

Is my presumption true? If not can anyone explain what is wrong here? Also how can I verify the result of `ToPrimitive([])` is 0 in any browser's console ?

Comment: Yet another reason to use `===`.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FqhZZNUyVFM

Comment: some explanation for video link by @valepu (enjoyed it) http://www.2ality.com/2012/01/object-plus-object.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Refer to the [`spec`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-toprimitive), the `[] == false` could be parsed as below form

```
ToNumber(ToPrimitive([])) == ToNumber(false)
```

Here are more details

> If Type(y) is Boolean, return the result of the comparison x == ToNumber(y)

```
[] == ToNumber(false)
```

> If Type(x) is Object and Type(y) is either String, Number, or Symbol, then return the result of the comparison ToPrimitive(x) == y

```
ToPrimitive([]) == 0
```

According to the `ToPrimitive` algorithm, `valueOf` is called first. But since that returns an object, not a primitive value, `toString` will be called secondly, which returns a string `''`, empty string

> If Type(x) is String and Type(y) is Number, return the result of the comparison ToNumber(x) == y

```
ToNumber('') == 0
```

Then after `ToNumber` to 0. Compare to `ToNumber(false)` is also 0. As a result, they are same.

Comment: Oh I see, Then my presumption is correct as coercion will be repeated until the both operands becomes primitive.  Right?

Comment: I just tested it in my console with `Number([].valueOf().toString()) == 0`. And it yields `true`. The link that you given is pretty much useful.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy why is it "pretty much" useful? It's just useful :) "pretty much" = "very nearly"

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy, yes, your presumption is right.

Answer (score 4):

The spec says

> If Type(y) is Boolean, return the result of the comparison x == ToNumber(y).

So yes, that means the [Abstract Equality Comparison](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-abstract-equality-comparison) will be called recursively until it returns true or false, or until an error is thrown. One of these will happen eventually, so it is guaranteed that the recursion will finish.

Step by step, it's

```
[] == false;
[] == +0; // ToNumber(false)
"" == +0; // ToPrimitive([])
+0 == +0; // ToNumber("")
true;
```

Note the recursion does not end iff both operands are primitives. For example, when you compare two objects, there is no recursion. Or when you compare two primitives of different types, there can be recursion.

And `ToPrimitive([])` is `""`, not `+0`. That's because

1. Arrays have no @@toPrimitive method, so OrdinaryToPrimitive is used instead
2. The abstract equality provides no hint, so Number is used
3. Then [`valueOf`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-object.prototype.valueof) (inherited from `Object.prototype`) is called first, but doesn't return a primitive.
4. Finally [`toString`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-array.prototype.tostring) (inherited from `Array.prototype`) is the last attempt. It does a `join`, which returns the empty string in this case. That's the primitive.

Comment: Nicely explained, plus 1. `when you compare two objects, there is no recursion`,  So that means `return false` stated at 10th line of AECA (abstract..) will be executed. Right?

Comment: You might want to add that while the spec might recurse, and even might recurse multiple times, it is guaranteed to terminate.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy Not sure what AECA means. When you compare two objects, the abstract equality comparison only calls the strict equality comparison, which is never recursive.

Comment: @Oriol I meant AECA as "Abstract equality comparison algorithm"

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy Ah, of course. When you compare two objects, since they have the same type, Abstract Equality Comparison calls Strict Equality Comparison at step 3.a, which will return true at step 8 or false at step 9.